# Parse Chat Room - Converting NS Array to NSMutableArray for DIsplay on Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, chatroom

I am trying to create a chat room and show "available chats" on a table view. 
I am trying to turn the *object NSArray to a NSMutableArray using mutableCopy and display that on the tableView ... but it seems to constantly crash....

any help appreciated.

.h

> @interface MMKMatchesViewController1 : UITableViewController

.m

> @interface MMKMatchesViewController1 () //
>
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
>   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *availableChatRooms;

The Code to update the chatrooms

> -(NSMutableArray *)availableChatRooms {
>       if (!_availableChatRooms){
>           _availableChatRooms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>       }
>       return _availableChatRooms; }

This is what should update the tableView

> - (void)updateAvailableChatRooms {
>     PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ChatRoom"];
>
>   [query whereKey:@"user1" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
>
>   PFQuery *queryInverse = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ChatRoom"];
>
>   [query whereKey:@"user2" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
>
>   PFQuery *queryCombined = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query, queryInverse]];
>
>   //[queryCombined includeKey:@"chat"];
>
>   [queryCombined includeKey:@"user1"];
>
>   [queryCombined includeKey:@"user2"];
>
>   [queryCombined findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
>
>   ```
>   if (!error){
>
>       [self.availableChatRooms removeAllObjects];
>
>       [self.tableView reloadData];
>
>       //[self.availableChatRooms addObjectsFromArray:objects]; <---NEED HELP HERE :-(
>
>       [self.availableChatRooms = objects mutableCopy];         <---NEED HELP HERE :-(
>
>       [self.tableView reloadData];
>
>
>   }
>   ```
>
>   }]; }

Table Data source

> - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
>
> return  [self.availableChatRooms count];
>
> }
>
> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>
>   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
>
>   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
>     forIndexPath:indexPath];
>
>   PFObject *chatRoom =[self.availableChatRooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
>
>   PFUser *likedUser;
>
>   PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
>
>   PFUser *testUser1 = chatRoom[@"user1"];
>
>   if ([testUser1.objectId isEqual:currentUser.objectId]) {
>
>   ```
>   likedUser =[chatRoom objectForKey:@"user2"];
>   ```
>
>   }
>     else {
>
>   ```
>   likedUser = [chatRoom objectForKey:@"user1"];
>   ```
>
>   }
>
>   cell.textLabel.text = likedUser[@"profile"][@"firstName"];
>
>   //344
>
>   //cell.imageView.image = place holder image
>
>   cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
>
>   PFQuery *queryForPhoto = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"Photo"];
>
>   [queryForPhoto whereKey:@"user" equalTo:likedUser];
>
>   [queryForPhoto findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
>
>   ```
>   if ([objects count] > 0){
>
>       PFObject *photo = objects[0];
>
>       PFFile *pictureFile = photo[kMMKPhotoPictureKey];
>
>       [pictureFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
>
>           cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageWithData:data];
>
>           cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
>       }];
>   }
>   ```
>
>   }];
>
>   return cell; }

@JAMIE - The error that shows once i press the button to goto the chat window

```
2014-11-08 12:34:21.468 Project1[19993:244958] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:6116
2014-11-08 12:34:21.472 Project1[19993:244958] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109727f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001093c0bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109727d9a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001076595df -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010806f864 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 153
    5   Jobazo                              0x000000010641877d -[MMKMatchesViewController1 tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 109
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010807c4b3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 508
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010805bfb1 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2846
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000108071e3c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000107ffe973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107c92de8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107c87a0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107c8787e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107bf563e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107bf674a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107bf6db5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010965cdc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010965cd20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109652b53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109652486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a8ba9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000107f85420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    22  Project1                            0x0000000106417c93 main + 115
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109c54145 start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks!

Comment: @DanielGalasko - if you know anything about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is not just a typo when you copied it to SO, your syntax is wrong. Here is your problem.

```
[self.availableChatRooms = objects mutableCopy];         <---NEED HELP HERE :-(
```

Although the fact that you said it crashes kind of confuses me, if this was the problem I'd suspect it would fail to compile.

What you want to do is

```
self.availableChatRooms = [objects mutableCopy];
```

Brackets are used for message passing in objective-c (that's and a few other things) so you'd be calling a method on availableChatRooms but you're trying to do an assignment within there.

If this isn't your problem and it is just a typo if you could provide the error that's outputted when it crashes that would help a lot.

---

EDIT:

According to the documentation at [the developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:).

> You must register a class or nib file using the `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method before calling this method.

I don't know what the rest of your code looks like but I'd assume that's where the problem would lie.

If you're creating your table view cells within a Storyboard it'll take care of registering the nib for you and you can use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method, see the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:)

(Be careful as this method will just return nil if there's no cells in the queue so you'll need to create a new cell yourself if it returns nil) also make sure your cell identifiers match those in your storyboard.

Comment: Hey Jamie - i did make the syntax change but it didn't seem to be affecting the initial performance, its still crashing ... but building successfully.. i updated the above to show the error that comes when i click the button to goto the chat screen

Answer (score 1):

This is a most excellent bug.

```
[self.availableChatRooms = objects mutableCopy];
```

[] needs an object on the left side, and a message on the right side.

The object is

```
self.availableChatRooms = objects
```

You are using an assignment operator here, which assigns "objects" to "self.availableChatRooms", and the result of that assignment operator is self.availableChatRooms, which is the same as objects.

Then you send the "mutableCopy" message to the object. Which creates a mutable copy, and because you didn't tell the compiler what to do with the result, it is thrown away. What you wrote is the same as

```
self.availableChatRooms = objects;
[self.availableChatRooms mutableCopy];
```

You wanted

```
self.availableChatRooms = [objects mutableCopy];
```

I suggest you turn all the warnings on in Xcode. I haven't tried it, but would expect that some warning is generated by your code.